# Spring - JPA - observe events

Tags: spring, jpa

I would like to observe when an entity is saved or deleted so that I may perform additional activities pertaining to that entity.  I thought I did this in the past WITHOUT using the @EntityListeners annotation on the entity class itself because my entity listeners would be implemented in the service layer and NOT in the model / data layer.

The only other way I can think of to do it is inside the persistence.xml and specify my listeners there.

Are there any alternate approaches?

Comment: Any use? https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2#transaction-bound-events

Comment: You can try building yourself a layer based on Spring AOP or you can check also [this article])(http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa) implementing auditing several ways.

Comment: @AlanHay that is actually the same article I came across - I thought I already had spring starter in my maven deps, but could not find CreationEvent.  I'll try that again, otherwise, that would be ideal.

Comment: @andrei-macarie that was exactly what I was trying to avoid.  I do NOT want to have the listener inside the entity class or even the entity know at compile time.  I want it to be a third-party library that does the observation.

Comment: @WalterWhite I understood your point of not trying to pollute your entities with auditing logic. I think that you can't escape adding several annotations to entities in order to add JPA mappings, audit and any other stuff that needs to be added. I say this because in JAVA you cannot create an API that can express fluently configuration for your entities - JAVA does not have the concept of expression trees. So your best bet will be to go at the provider level. So if you are using JPA + Hibernate then you can check Hibernate ENVERS in the article I've sent you.

Comment: @WalterWhite also check the [Envers Docs section 21.14. Conditional auditing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers). You will have to polute your entities with `@Audited` but the rest will be done outside your entities.

Comment: @WalterWhite you already know how stuff is being mapped in JPA using JAVA annotations. Now look at Entity Framework Fluent Mapping for .NET - [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx). Is easy to observe the power of expression trees. When Java as a language will support such a feature then maybe we will have separate classes to delegate separate concerns by mapping fluently in a type safe manner. I know you can use reflection and hardcoded strings but don't think anyone wants to do that. Thus the annotation solution placed on entities.

Comment: @AlanHay - yes, somewhat, but unfortunately, I cannot seem to get that to work.  I've seen that setup in a few places, but the only events I can observe with that are the Spring events (container / context initialized ...).  I am using spring boot and running a very primitive test.  I've enabled transaction management and fallback, but nothing.

Comment: I am planning to use AspectJ here, but that seems like just a hack to get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away, and the answer was in my question.

The solution (that I wanted, but disliked because of using XML) was to:

1. write a generic entity listener using annotations, and get a programmatic instance of the bean manager (CDI), or equivalent in spring, then fire an event which I can process either via CDI or spring
2. where I want that listener to work, place a persistence.xml file and manually specify the entity-listeners there
3. if I want to do anything special, I simply observe the event that I'm interested in and I get the information that I want.